# Transfer MainMenu Items to MenuStrip?

Tags: vb.net, mdi, menustrip

I work on MDI winform app in VB. One form which become child of my MDI have a mainMenu control with a lot of items. I want to show this mainMenu control on specific panel of MDI, or to add all of it's items on MenuStrip control which is on MDI?

Comment: MainMenu and MenuStrip are water and fire.  You'll need to retire that MainMenu and *replace* it with a MenuStrip.